# Update route params when selection changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my Vue.js (2.x) app I have a component that represents a mailbox, i.e. displays a list of messages. The component's route is defined thus:

```
{
  path: '/messages/:messageId',
  name: 'messages',
  component: Messages,

  // this sets the component's messageId prop to the same value as the route param
  props: true
}
```

When the component is created, the messages are loaded from the server. If the `messageId` route param is specified, the message with this ID will be selected initially

```
props: {
  messageId: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
    default: null
  }
},
data () {
  return {
    allMessages: [],
    selectedMessage: null
  }
},
async created () {
  this.allMessages = await messageService.loadMessages()

  if (this.messageId) {
    this.selectedMessage = this.allMessages.find(message => message.id == this.messageId);
  }
}
```

When the user clicks on a message, `selectedMessage` is updated. I would also like to update the `messageId` route param such that the user could (for example)

- click on a message
- copy the (updated) URL from the browser's address bar
- open a new tab and paste the URL to reload the page with the same message selected

However, I'm not sure how to update the route param when the selected message changes? I guess I could do something like

```
methods: {
  onMessageSelected (selectedMessage) {
    this.selectedMessage = selectedMessage
    const params = { messageId: selectedMessage.id }
    this.$router.push({ name: 'messages', params: params } })
  }
}
```

But this reloads the whole route/component, causing the list of messages to be fetched again, which is very inefficient. Is there a way to just update the route param in the URL without reloading the route/component?

Comment: You should be able to leverage `history.pushState` without using `vue-router` for simply updating the url without triggering stateful changes in vue-router.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you could try:

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'messages', params: params } })
```

Or

```
this.$router.push({ path: `/messages/${messageId}`})
```

Comment: There is no route named "messages-messageId" so I don't see how your first suggestion could work